# Grails internationalization with Ember.js and Handlebars.js

Tags: grails, internationalization, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm developing a web application and I'd need some advice on how to solve the following 'problem' of internationalization.

I use `Grails 2.2.0` along with `Ember.js` and `Handlebars.js` whereas the frontend (which is realised through JavaScript with the before mentioned frameworks) is residing in it's on project with the `Sass` files for styling `Grunt.js` for compiling the whole thing.

Within this 'frontend project' I create the `handlebars` templates which I want to deliver via `Grails` on demand, with the full text of the template being internationalized through the server side (`Grails`) according to the locale of the logged in user. So, the workflow would be something like the following:

1. Client (JS) -> requests Backend (Grails)
2. Backend Controller checks if the user has permission to access this method, checks the set `locale` of the user, precompiles the according `template` (handlebars) with the correct `i18n` file, fetches the needed `data` and returns a `JSON` object with `data` and `tmpl` values
3. Backend (Grails) responses to Client (JS)
4. Client takes template, caches it if possible and compiles it with the given data set to place

Is there a proper `Grails` plugin for this issue? If I'm searching for 'handlebars' at the Grails Plugin page I get 3 matches:

- Handlebars Plugin
- Handlbars Resources Plugin
- EmberJS templates precompiler Plugin

I read through the documentation of all of them but I'm still not sure whether any of this plugins could be used to what I'm looking for or not. The reason why I want to do it like this is, that I have very large (and by that I mean VERY LARGE) `i18n` files in at least 12 different languages which I don't want to send to the client per se...

Has anybody had the same issue/problem/challenge and could provide me some information to this topic? Or is my approach complete nonsense and I should try another way?